# Task to prove consequence

Tags: logic

I have two simple math logic tasks, which i try to solve using this rules http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf but i must be missing something.

⊢ (AvB) -> AB

What i ve tried:

1. AvB ⊢ AB

2.and then expanding AB as ¬(A->¬B) and AvB as ¬A->B, but nothing good comes out of it

A->B ⊢ (A->(B->C))->(A->C)

What i ve tried:

1. A->B, (A->(B->C)) ⊢ (A->C)
2. A, A->B, (A->(B->C)) ⊢ C

Answer (score 1):

But hold on! $(A \lor B) \to AB$ is not a logical validity, is it?

The fact one of $A, B$ is true (i.e. $A \lor B$) doesn't imply that they are both true, does it?!

> Moral: before blindly trying to apply rules to prove some wff, **stop and think**. Ask yourself: (1) What
>   does this wff actually mean? Does that actually look like a logical
>   truth? If so why? (2) Then, given what it actually means, how would I
>   prove that informally -- and [finally] can I regiment that informal
>   proof into my official formal proof system?

In this case, you should really have spotted the problem at step (1)!

Comment: Thanks! I realise (AvB) -> AB is not true, but how to prove so is what i dont understand

Comment: Then you need to be more explicit in how you ask your question. What you want to show, then, is $\nvdash (A \lor B) \to AB$, the negation of what you wrote. Use a truth table to show  $(A \lor B) \to AB$ is not valid, and then it immediately follows that your rules can't prove it as your rules only allow you to prove validities.